# I want to redirect all requests to main domain

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

When write `https://new.example.com/course/comptia` 
and go to source code, write all requests send to index.php in htaccess
then when view url in my source code with plugins alls send to index.php
like App/Assets/... when click on it send me to 
`https://new.example.com/course/App/Assets/...`

course-> not directory how when click to App/Assets/... Send Me
To https://new.example.com/App/Assets/... 
To Main domain without query request uri ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this adding to your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !.(js|gif|jpg|png|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|map)$ index.php

</IfModule>`

Comment: This is My htaccess but not work You can check this `https://new.arabcbt.com/course/CompTIA_Security+501`

Answer (score 0):

in ur .htaccess try to do like this example :

```
RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !oldexample.com$ [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```